# Como cria uma trigger de inserção

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso montar uma `trigger` para que toda vez que inserir um dado numa  tabela `usuario`, insira automaticamente o mesmo dado em uma outra tabela `bkuser`. Como posso fazer isso? Uso PHP. E como invoca a `trigger`?

Comment: Recomendo a leitura http://www.devmedia.com.br/mysql-triggers/8088 e https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: Posta aí o que você já tem pra ajudar quem for responder... (Não fui eu quem deu -1, até porque meus votos de hoje acabaram, só daqui duas horas  rsrs)

Comment: Então você ia dar -1 @gustavox ? Brinks kkkkk

Comment: Nem eu que dei -1. Prefiro antes dialogar com o OP a respeito da pergunta e dar a ele uma outra chance de melhora-la. :)

Comment: kkkkk nem @WilliamOkano eu ia dar +1 porque achei injusto. A pergunta pareceu interessante, pena que o AP não traz nenhum código, e acho que por isso tomou -1...

Comment: @gustavox hehe, acho que entendi o que ele quis... só acho. Fiz um post, espero que seja o que ele precisa. Hora de hunger games, flw

Comment: @DiegoFelipe, eu dou -1 e peço resgate "Se melhorar sua pergunta, devolvo sua reputação!" :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trigger é relativa ao banco de dados e não a linguagem.

Uma trigger é criada justamente para ser invocada automaticamente antes ou após alguma coisa.

Por exemplo, posso criar um log para auditoria, sempre após eu atualizar algum registro na tabela que possui a trigger. Exemplo:

```sql
create table usuarios (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    nome varchar (45) not null
);

create table usuarios_alteracoes_historico (
    id_usuario int not null,
    nome varchar (45) not null,
    constraint fk_usuario_historico_alteracao foreign key (id_usuario) references usuarios (id)
);

CREATE TRIGGER usuarios_salva_historico
AFTER UPDATE ON usuarios
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO usuarios_alteracoes_historico (id_usuario, nome) VALUES
(NEW.id, OLD.nome); END//

insert into usuarios (nome) values
('william'), ('roberto');

update usuarios set nome = 'william okano' where nome = 'william';

select * from usuarios;
select * from usuarios_alteracoes_historico;
```

No caso para "ativar a trigger" basta você fazer um insert na tabela usuarios que será "transparente" pra você a inserção na tabela de historico.

Cabe a você agora adaptar para o que você precisa, pois sua pergunta está mal elaborada e confusa.

Comment: +1 Mas ele ainda pode melhorar a pergunta, e pra fazer sentido você terá que mudar a resposta! :P

Comment: Resolveu obrigado